# cant run my server because of uwsgi

Tags: python, windows, uwsgi

im working on a project which included uwsgi. when i tried to pip install it it figured the problem with the uname and read about it in the net, that i need to change for platform.os or some like this.  but i dont know how to do it. is it possible to make it to work on windows? i dont want to work with linux (kind of a starter i should say).

someone told me after i showed him this msg :

Running: uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:5000 --http-websockets --threaded  --master  --wsgi Screen:app
'uwsgi' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(when i tried to open the server for checking) that i should install uwsgi for windows and not for python itself but how? i dont get it..

ty

Comment: I've never used uwsgi on windows but when it says 'uwsgi' is not recognized, that means you're not correctly calling the executable. Try `uwsgi.exe --http 127.0.0.1:5000 --http-websockets --threaded --master --wsgi Screen:app`. That may not completely work either but will hopefully at least uncover what the next step needs to be.

Comment: try to use: `where uwsgi.exe` If you got errormessage instead of filepath, than you have to switch current directory to the right folder or add path to uwsgi.exe into system path variable and reboot.

Comment: ty for your comments but it didnt work. when i tryied: where uwsgi.exe it said that  it cant find files for the given patterns. and when i wanted to add  system path varible i tried to search first for this file but it cant find him.  i think its because i never install it because of the error that when i do pip install uwsgi it send the error with the os.uname that not recognized on windows. any help?

Comment: After a little googling it appears there's no windows package currently available for uwsgi. It sounds like it can be built from source using cygwin but if you're set on sticking with windows, you might be better off finding a WSGI server that supports windows.